# Changing the value of an integer according to the result of an if statment

Tags: vba, excel

I have this function:

```
Public Price As Integer

Public Function MergeSize(r As Range) As Long

MergeSize = r(1).MergeArea.Cells.Count

If MergeSize <= 10 Then
    Price = 70
    MergeSize = MergeSize * price
Elseif MergeSize > 10 And MergeSize <= 21 Then
    Price = 65
    MergeSize = MergeSize * price
Else
    Price = 60
    MergeSize = MergeSize * Price
End If

End Function
```

The thing is, that I would like to use "Price" in another `Sub` and have it displayed according to the if statement's result.

Here is the part of the sub where I would like to use it:

```
Dim Charge As Long
Charge = MergeSize(ActiveCell)
MsgBox "Daily rate of: " & Price & vbNewLine & "Total     is: " &  Charge
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you want to run this code now from VBA (and not from Excel cell as UDF), change your calling `Sub` code to:

```
Sub test()

Dim Charge As Long

'Charge = MergeSize(Range("B1")) '<-- send the range in the brackets
' === Active Cell ====
Charge = MergeSize(ActiveCell) '<-- send ActiveCell as range in the brackets

MsgBox "Daily rate of: " & Price & vbNewLine & "Total     is: " & Charge

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks again, Shai. As you might recall I need to have the range put into mergesize using the mouse to choose diffrent merged cells each time. I, actually, wasn't sure if I wrote the if statment correctly. Sorry I forgot to add here the active cell part. Ill add it now

Comment: Thanks. So that's actually how I wrote the code in excel. Its wierd, though, because at first, when I press play on the sub, it runs correctly, abd then it takes me back to the mergesize function as if there is something wrong with it. Then, when I press play again it displays the message box correctly.

Comment: @Eran you don;t need to first line `'Charge = MergeSize(Range("B1"))`, only `Charge = MergeSize(ActiveCell)` . Anyway, if all is ok, Ten li **V** :)

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't ezplain myself well... The code in excel is written like said, with Charge = MergeSize(ActiveCell), but it doent work. It stops and only when I click play again it shows the correct messagebox

Comment: @Eran I'm not following you, did you copy the code from my `Sub test` above ? isn't it working for you while your mouse is on `ActiveCell` ?

Comment: @Eran:"when I press play on the sub, it runs correctly, abd then it takes me back to the mergesize function as if there is something wrong with it" Sure you have not set a break point in the code of MergeSize function?

Comment: @Axel: Im not sure what you mean by that, but until now I just used numbers instade: MergeSize = MergeSize * 60 (ofcourse I didnt try to display that in the message box yet), and everything worked fine...

Comment: @Eran:Open the VBA editor and look at the code of the `MergeSize` function. Is there a red point somewhere left before a code line and this code line is highlighted red? This would be a break point.

Comment: Axel: No. But when I run the code it takes me to the     MergeSize    function, and highlights the first line in yellow with a yellow arrow to the left of it. That is this line: Public Function MergeSize(r As Range) As Long

Comment: @Eran the yellow line with error is on the line `MergeSize = r(1).MergeArea.Cells.Count` ?

Comment: Ok. Im not sure what I did, but everything works fine now. Thank you very much my (first!!!) Code is done:)

Comment: @Eran  lo mefargen li batshuva ?

Comment: Sure:) but what do you think about my answer?

Answer (score 1):

I should have written it like this:

```
Public Price As Integer

Public Function MergeSize(r As Range) As Long

MergeSize = r(1).MergeArea.Cells.Count


    If MergeSize <= 10 Then
    Price = 70

Elseif MergeSize > 10 And MergeSize <= 21 Then
    Price = 65

Else
    Price = 60

End If

MergeSize = MergeSize * Price
End Function
```

Comment: you are right, there is no need to repeat `MergeSize = MergeSize * price` for each case, since they are the same

Comment: :) toda raba, Shai!